# Try to update\fetch Postgres json column into JsValue using anorm

Tags: json, postgresql, playframework-2.0, anorm

**Update:**
If I use plain JsValue it works, but Option[JsValue] fails!

I am trying to read and update a json field in postgres using anorm.
The following code should update the json:

```
def update(id:Long, data:Option[JsValue]){
   SQL(
      """UPDATE my_table
        |SET data = {data}
        |WHERE id = {id}
      """.stripMargin)
   .on(
       'id -> id, 
       'data -> data
   ).executeUpdate() 
}
```

This is not compiling with the following error:

```
[error]  found   : (Symbol, Option[play.api.libs.json.JsValue])
[error]  required: anorm.NamedParameter
[error]             'data -> data
```

So based on some reading I did, I tried to add an implicit conversion

```
implicit def columnToJsValue:Column[JsValue] = anorm.Column.nonNull1[JsValue] { (value, meta) =>
  val MetaDataItem(qualified, nullable, clazz) = meta
  value match {
    case json:org.postgresql.util.PGobject=> Right(Json.parse(json.getValue))
    case _=> Left(TypeDoesNotMatch(s"Cannot convert $value: ${value.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].getClass} to Json for column $qualified"))
  }
}
```

and

```
implicit val jsonToStatement = new ToStatement[JsValue] {
  def set(s: PreparedStatement, i: Int, json: JsValue):Unit={
    val jsonObject=new org.postgresql.util.PGobject()
    jsonObject.setType("json")
    jsonObject.setValue(Json.stringify(json))
    s.setObject(i, jsonObject)
  }
}
```

But it still doesn't work.
What am I missing here?
Thanks!

Comment: Its working in my test env. Are those implicits in scope? Only change I made was `anorm.Column.nonNull1` to `anorm.Column.nonNull`, I guess that was a typo.

Comment: Yes I put them just above the update method. Can you share your imports?@johny

Comment: Ok my mistake it's Option[JsValue] I will update my post.

Comment: This too works. Only change I made is to give an implicit connection using, `DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>` for update method.